# dataframes have different sizes when referencing same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a strange problem. I have a dataset that I'm trying to select unique values from then save those values into a dataframe. After that, I want one dataframe with all the data and another with simply a numerical value. Both dataframes should be the same size.

Here's my loop and not sure why it's not working:

```
for uniqueFundName in HoldingCompanies['fund_ticker'].unique():
  print(uniqueFundName)
  modelY = (HoldingCompanies.loc[HoldingCompanies['fund_ticker'] == uniqueFundName]) 
  modelX = modelY['fund_ticker']
  modelX['fund_ticker'] = 1

  del modelY['fund_ticker']
  print(modelX.shape)
  print(modelY.shape)
```

This is my output:

```
GBRE.LSE
(234,)
(233, 174)
MACEX.US
(35,)
(34, 174)
ANFVX.US
(43,)
(42, 174)
LQGH.LSE
(11,)
(10, 174)
HAC.TO
(39,)
(38, 174)
JSAYX.US
(26,)
(25, 174)
```

The modelX is always one value less than the modelY variable. This is confusing because I'm referencing the modelY value to create the modelX column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelY['fund_ticker']` is a pandas `Series` object, when trying to access it later using `modelX['fund_ticker']=1`, you are simply adding another value to the series in the index 'fund_ticker' with a value of 1 to the exact same Series. So the size of `modelX` is increasing in 1 since basically all you did was add another row to the Series.

Comment: To add to above, if you want to set all values to 1, as it seems you are trying to do, try `modelX.loc[:] = 1`

Comment: agh thank you, is there a way to create that filtered dataframe modelY that isn't a series

Comment: @Lostsoul wrap the index in another square brackets: `modelY[['fund_ticker']]`